# How do I clip a line segment between two known y values?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I am implementing an algorithm to find an optimal label location for a polygon. It can be found [HERE.](http://mapcontext.com/autocarto/proceedings/auto-carto-8/pdf/an-algorithm-for-locating-candidate-labeling-boxes-within-a-polygon.pdf)

The gist is that I must sort the polygon's vertices by their `y` values. Then, for each `y` "draw" a horizontal line at that point. This divides the polygon into strips and it ends up looking like this:

[image: subdivided polygon]

Once these strips are created, I must find the midpoints of all the segments contained in each one. This is where I get stuck. For example, in strip #2, the leftmost segment has no endpoints to define it in that strip's scope. Its endpoints are at the top of strip #1 and the bottom of strip #3.

How do I clip the longer line segment to be a segment that is contained entirely in the upper and lower bounds of strip #2?

More specifically, how do I determine that those two endpoints (top of strip 1, bottom of strip 3) are the endpoints for the line that will be intersecting strip #2 on the left side?

Comment: The label is rectangle?

Comment: My labels will be small circles

Comment: That's fine. You can connect some nodes to make the polygon be convex polygon. Then you can use the algorithm.

Comment: That approach will not work for me. My shapes are often quite concave and irregular.

Comment: Can label cross the line? I mean if there is a part of the label out of the polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classical approach is to keep an "active list" that stores the indexes of the edges straddling the current ordinate. When you go from an ordinate to the next, edges can enter or leave the list (they do it once only). Keep it updated.

The list is initially empty, ends up empty and should contain an even number of edges at all times.

If the polygon edges never cross, you can keep the list ordered from left to right.

Comment: By the way, this is explained in the section "COMPUTING THE VERTICAL SEGMENTS".

Comment: This is the part I am having trouble following: "If the y coordinate following the current y coordinate is greater than the
previous y coordinate in the polygon boundary, the line is removed from the
active list. If this is not the case, the line segment is recorded in the list." Since the vertices are already sorted along the y axis, isn't this implicit?

Comment: Let me try to clarify what sounds right to me: I need a list of edges in addition to my list of points. As I move up my list of strips, I need to check and see which edges are intersecting the current strip. If they intersect, I add the edge to the active list. If an edge is in the active list, and it no longer intersects with the current strip, it is removed from the active list. At each strip iteration, I record which edges were active, where I can then clip them based on the upper and lower bounds of the strip. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: There are "up" and "down" edges. When you reach a vertex, the down edges of which it is an endpoint enter the list and the up edges of which it is an endpoint enter the list. Your understanding seems correct. Run the algorithm "on paper".

Comment: Thanks, that makes much more sense now.